# Cannot find protocol declaration for JournalrComposeViewControllerDelegate even though header file has been imported

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, delegates, protocols

I am trying to make my own custom delegate in order to pass data back to the previous view controller and it is giving me the "Cannot find protocol declaration for JournalrComposeViewControllerDelegate" even though it is clearly defined and the header file included.Please Help!
Code: 
The JournalrViewController .h file that is trying to subscribe to the  Custom Delegate of JournalrComposeViewController:

```
//  JournalrViewController.h
//  Journalr
//
//  Created by Kevin Turner on 7/16/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Kevin Turner. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "JournalrAppDelegate.h"
#import "JournalrComposeViewController.h"

@interface JournalrViewController : UIViewController <JournalrComposeViewControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) CGFloat cY;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL returning;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *entryLabel;
@property (nonatomic) int totlal;

@end
```

The JournalrViewController .m file:

```
    //
//  JournalrViewController.m
//  Journalr
//
//  Created by Kevin Turner on 7/16/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Kevin Turner. All rights reserved.
//

#import "JournalrViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "JournalrComposeViewController.h"

@interface JournalrViewController ()

@end

@implementation JournalrViewController
@synthesize cY;
@synthesize scrollView;
@synthesize entryLabel;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    cY = 50;
    self.returning = NO;

        [self fetchEntrys];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



-(void)deleteButtonPressed
{
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed");
}

- (void)fetchEntrys
{

    JournalrAppDelegate *appDelegate =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context =
    [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc =
    [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entrys"
                inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];

    //NSPredicate *pred =
    //[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(photoName = %@)",
     //@"1234"];
    //[request setPredicate:pred];
    NSManagedObject *matches = nil;

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request
                                              error:&error];

    if ([objects count] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"No matches");
    } else {


        NSLog(@"Matches found");



        matches = objects[1];

        NSString *firstEntry = [matches valueForKey:@"entry"];
        NSLog(@"First Entry: %@", firstEntry);
        self.totlal = [objects count];
         int i = [objects count] - 1;
        NSLog(@"%i", i);
        while ( i >  -1) {
            matches = objects[i];
            NSString *entry = [matches valueForKey:@"entry"];
            NSDate *date = [matches valueForKey:@"date"];
            NSDateFormatter *formatDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
            [formatDate setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YY"];
            NSString *dateString = [formatDate stringFromDate:date];


            NSLog(@"Date: %@", dateString);
             NSLog(@"Entry: %@", entry);

            UILabel *dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            dateLabel.text = dateString;
            dateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, cY, 100, 30);
            dateLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
            dateLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:24.0];

            UIButton *deleteButton  = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, dateLabel.frame.origin.y, 70, 27)];
            [deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            [deleteButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"delete.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


            cY += 35;

            UILabel *labelEntry = [[UILabel alloc]init];
            labelEntry.numberOfLines = 0;
            labelEntry.text = entry;
            CGRect lblFrame =  CGRectMake(20, cY, 280, 1000);
            labelEntry.frame = lblFrame;
            labelEntry.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
            labelEntry.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [labelEntry sizeToFit];





            UILabel *outerLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, cY - 50, 300, labelEntry.frame.size.height + 80)];
            [scrollView addSubview:outerLabel];

            outerLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
            outerLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;

            //UIImageView *backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, cY, 312, labelEntry.frame.size.height)];
            //backgroundImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
            //backgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"post.jpg"];
            //NSLog(@"Image Height :%f", backgroundImage.frame.size.height);

            //[scrollView addSubview:backgroundImage];






            cY += labelEntry.frame.size.height;
            NSLog(@"Label Height: %f", labelEntry.frame.size.height);
            NSLog(@"currenty: %f", cY);
            cY += 100.f;

            scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
            scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
            [scrollView addSubview: labelEntry];
            [scrollView addSubview:dateLabel];
            [scrollView addSubview:deleteButton];

                        i--;
        }

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, cY);
        NSLog(@"cY: %f", cY);

     }


}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    JournalrComposeViewController* controller = [segue destinationViewController];
    controller.delegate = self;
}

-(void)refresh {
    NSLog(@"IT WORKED!");

}



@end
```

The JournalrComposeViewController .h file:

```
//
//  JournalrComposeViewController.h
//  Journalr
//
//  Created by Kevin Turner on 7/17/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Kevin Turner. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "JournalrAppDelegate.h"

@class JournalrComposeViewController;

@protocol JournalrComposeViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)refresh;

@end

@interface JournalrComposeViewController : UIViewController<UITextViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *saveButton;
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <JournalrComposeViewControllerDelegate>delegate;
@end
```

And finally the JournalrComposeViewController .m file:

```
//
//  JournalrComposeViewController.m
//  Journalr
//
//  Created by Kevin Turner on 7/17/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Kevin Turner. All rights reserved.
//

#import "JournalrComposeViewController.h"
#import "JournalrViewController.h"
@interface JournalrComposeViewController ()

@end

@implementation JournalrComposeViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.textView becomeFirstResponder];
    self.textView.delegate = self;
    self.saveButton.enabled = self.textView.text.length > 0;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{


}



- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
 self.saveButton.enabled = self.textView.text.length > 0;   
}


- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {



    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];


    NSLog(@"%@", date);

    JournalrAppDelegate *appDelegate =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context =
    [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *newEntry;
    newEntry = [NSEntityDescription
                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entrys"
                  inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [newEntry setValue: self.textView.text forKey:@"entry"];
    [newEntry setValue: date forKey:@"date"];
    [newEntry setValue: @"1234" forKey:@"photoName"];
    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];
    JournalrViewController *journalr = [[JournalrViewController alloc]init];
    journalr.returning = TRUE;

    [self.delegate refresh];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    }];

}

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    }];

}
@end
```

Comment: Please check, if you have an import cycle and break it, if so.

Comment: What is an import cycle? Please enlighten me

Comment: A.h imports b.h and b.h imports a.h (or a imports c that imports b and so on). #import rejects reimports, so one header misses declarations in the other one. Enlightened? You can Break that with forward declarations.

Comment: That does not quite seem to be the source of the problem, the problem still persists even after using a forward class declaration :(

Comment: 1. Did you break the import cycle? Please analyse this, it is not easy to see, if there are more than 2 headers involved. 2. Protocols has forward declarations, too.

Comment: Amin:  Yes. that is the problem I had.  Once I solved the import cycle, the error went away.